# auto-fill pandas df from equation?

Tags: python, pandas

I've got some code that works, but I'd rather it be condensed:

```
temps = pd.DataFrame()
temps['T'] = beststns['ave']
temps['T2'] = np.square(temps['T'])
temps['T3'] = temps['T2']*temps['T']
temps['T(t-1)'] = temps['T'].shift(1)
temps['T2(t-1)'] = np.square(temps['T(t-1)'])
temps['T3(t-1)'] = temps['T2(t-1)']*temps['T(t-1)']
temps['T(t-2)'] = temps['T(t-1)'].shift(1)
temps['T2(t-2)'] = np.square(temps['T(t-2)'])
temps['T3(t-2)'] = temps['T2(t-2)']*temps['T(t-2)']
```

I'd like to fill my dataframe with each of the variables above (T, T^2, and T^3, and then the same values for observation (t-1), (t-2), ... (t-n)).  I've got it manually, but ideally I'd like to condense the code, so that I can just type what "n" should be (for the number of temperature lags to include in my model).

Any ideas for how this can be condensed?

*Edit:
What I'd like to see in my dataframe is this:

```
            T           T2             T3  T(t-1)      T2(t-1)        T3(t-1)  
0      45.125  2036.265625   91886.486328   0.000     0.000000       0.000000   
1      45.250  2047.562500   92652.203125  45.125  2036.265625   91886.486328   
2      44.625  1991.390625   88865.806641  45.250  2047.562500   92652.203125
```

I'm starting with a df that looks like this:

```
            T
0      45.125
1      45.250
2      44.625
```

With the following code:

```
l = 1
pd.concat([temps,temps['T'].shift(l).add_suffix('(t-'+str(l)+')')])
```

I get the following output:

```
               T      T2        T3     0
0           43.0  1849.0   79507.0   NaN
1           41.0  1681.0   68921.0   NaN
2           40.0  1600.0   64000.0   NaN
...          ...     ...       ...   ...
35034(t-1)   NaN     NaN       NaN  54.0
35035(t-1)   NaN     NaN       NaN  55.0
35036(t-1)   NaN     NaN       NaN  54.0
```

Aka, I'm not concating correctly (I thought it was of the form

```
pd.concat([df1, df4], axis=1)
```

?)

And I'm not adding my suffix to the column name correctly.  Ideally I'd like to get somewhere like this:

```
pd.concat([temps,(temps['T'].shift(l).add_suffix('(t-'+str(l)+')') for l in lag),1])
```

Update:

Thanks to Raunaq, this works:

```
T = 'T(t-'
T2 = 'T2(t-'
T3 = 'T3(t-'
for i in lag:
    t = T + str(i) + ')'
    t2 = T2 + str(i) + ')'
    t3 = T3 + str(i) + ')'
    temps[t] = temps.iloc[:,-3].shift(1)
    temps[t2] = temps.iloc[:,-3].shift(1)
    temps[t3] = temps.iloc[:,-3].shift(1)
```

As my original question went down the pathway of concatenation, was this the wrong tree to bark up?  I'd prefer to make this as condensed as possible (ideally one line).

Comment: Please take the time to prepare sample data and show us what you want the result to look like.  This takes effort to answer, we'd at least like to see that you've put in effort to ask.  This isn't meant to be an admonition, but friendly advice.  I'd like to see you edit this so that someone can answer it.  Also, read [mcve] to get a good idea of what I'm talking about.

Comment: That's fair, thank you for the feedback.  Would it be reasonable to edit it to say that I'm working on a solution?

Comment: Yes.  Maybe put at the top "MCVE in progress ..."

Comment: @bearcub, according to your expected output, aren't you just shifting the first 3 columns by 1 for each n?

Answer (score 0):

```
temps['T'] = beststns['ave']
temps['T2'] = np.square(temps['T'])
temps['T3'] = temps['T2']*temps['T']

a = 'T(t-'
b = 'T2(t-'
c = 'T3(t-'
for i in range(1, n+1):
    val = str(i) + ')'
    a = a + val
    b = b + val
    c = c + val
    temps[a] = temps.iloc[:,-3].shift(i)
    temps[b] = np.square(temps.iloc[:,-1])
    temps[c] = temps.iloc[:,-2] * temps.iloc[:,-2]
```

Comment: Thanks Raunaq.  I'm not sure this part will work though:

    temps[c] = temps.iloc[:,-2] * temps.iloc[:,-2]

As this will index T(t-1), and then square it.  (Cubed is needed.)

I've updated above with help from your suggestion.